# Is there anyway to get how long the list is in Haskell without using the length function in this situation?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have to define a function according to this signature:

```
indexList :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
```

The function is supposed to unzip the list elements into a tuple - the first part of the tuple being how far is the tuple from the end of the list - and the second part being the original element itself. (Must be recursive, and I can't use the length function).

expecting this test to be true:

```
indexList [True, False, True] == [(2, True), (1, False), (0, True)]
```

I have gotten here so far:

```
indexList [] = []
indexList (x : xs) = ({-HowFarIsIt-}, x) : indexList xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the result of the next tuple of the result, so:

```
indexList :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
indexList [] = []
indexList [x] = [(0, x)]
indexList (x : xs) = … : ys
    where ys@((i,_):_) = indexList xs
```

where I leave filling in `…` as an exercise.

You can also work with a helper function to enable total pattern matching:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty(NonEmpty((:|)), (<|))

indexList :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
indexList [] = []
indexList (x : xs) = let (x :| xs) = indexList' x xs in x : xs

indexList' :: a -> [a] -> NonEmpty [(a, Int)]
indexList' x [] = (0, x) :| []
indexList' x xs = … <| ys
    where ys@((i,_) :| _) = indexList' x xs
```

Comment: The incomplete pattern match makes me sad. I wonder if there's a simple way to get rid of it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: you could use a helper function that returns a 2-tuple with the first item and second, or return a `NonEmpty` thus, and work with that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid it was going to have to look like. I originally thought of a much shorter and simpler-looking approach along the lines of `indexList (x:xs) = case indexList xs of ...`, but then I realized that would have basically all of the same problems with (i.e., lack of) laziness and performance that `reverse . zip [0..] . reverse` would.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica How about `indexList (x:xs) = let ys = indexList xs in (case ys of [] -> 0; (i,_):_ -> i+1, x):ys`?

Comment: Oftentimes, partiality is necessity. You just know e.g. a result list has length >= 2, and you could possibly prove it with prover languages, but haskell is not cut for that.